# Exchange migration to 2007 making Outlook 2003 unable to read meeting requests

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, outlook-2003

We are currently moving from Exchange 2003 to 2007 (8.2 build 176.2).

We have encounted an issue with one user.

In Outlook 2003 when getting a meeting request:

"Can't open this item.  Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are nto valid."

The item cannot be previewed in the reading pane either.

The item can be viewed in OWA and iPhone fine.

I've tried with cache mode off and on. Different computers. Same issue.

There are the following entries on the account:

SMTP
firstname@companyname.com.au
flastname@companyname.com.au

X400
C=AU;A= ;P=Company Name;O=Exchange;S=LastName;G=FirstName;

I'm loathe to recreate the account. This will be an extreme last resort.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the entire store was bad. Recreated the store. Everything is ok now. Eseutil shows nothing wrong with the store that was causing the issue, not entire sure how to go about further fault finding it. Will probably call MS and see where it goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the item being created through OWA?  I've heard of issues with OWA-created meetings causing issues using Outlook 2003 with Exchange 2007.

Try having the associated user launch Outlook with the /CleanFreeBusy switch; this will regenerate meeting information and can often fix a lot of meeting-request-related errors.

Also, make sure the Outlook 2003 clients are fully hotfixed, as there were some hotfixes dealing with 2007 compatibility released.

Comment: Calendar items are created via Outlook 2003. 

Tried Outlook with /CleanFreeBusy switch, also most of the other switches. No luck.

Outlook 2003 clients are all up to date as well. We've migrated ~40 users with only this one issue.